# polymorphic functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Have a parametrically polymorphic function `foo :: a -> a -> a`. Give four of the argument so that the resulting expression
`foo arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4` would have type `Bool`.

```
-- foo :: a -> a -> a function is defined in a code 
arg1 = undefined
arg2 = undefined
arg3 = undefined
arg4 = undefined
```

Comment: arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4 :: a -> a -> Bool

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's home work. Not  a really a programming question.

Comment: @mb14 ... homework questions are fine on SO

Comment: hint: assuming the function does not *cheat* - all it has is the choice to return one of it's arguments and `foo arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4  = (((foo arg1) arg2) arg3) arg4`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint, only.

Function `foo` takes two arguments since its type is `a -> a -> a`. However, `foo arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4` passes *four* arguments. How can that work?

Well, we can interpret `foo arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4` as

```
let bar = foo arg1 arg2
in bar arg3 arg4
```

This can only work if the result of `foo arg1 arg2` is a function (`bar`) expecting two arguments. But we know that the type of `bar` must be `a` from the type of `foo`. Hence, the type variable `a` must be chosen to be the type of a binary function, i.e. something like `b -> c -> d`.

Summing up, if `foo :: a -> a -> a`, then we also have

```
foo :: (b -> c -> d) -> (b -> c -> d) -> (b -> c -> d)
```